# $(\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{Z}), d)$ isometrically embeds in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$, where $d$ is the symmetric difference cardinality metric.

Tags: real-analysis

Define a metric on the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ as follows:
$$d(A,B)=\text{the cardinality of} (A\cup B\setminus(A\cap B)).$$ The resulting metric space admits an isometry in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I could not come up with any idea for this problem. Any hint/idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an idea what element in $\mathbb{R}$ you would map a finite set $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ to?

Comment: So $\forall i \ne 0, d(\{0\}, \{0,i\}) = 1$. And $\forall i, j \ne 0, i \ne j, d(\{0, i\}, \{0, j\}) = 2$. This is not possible in $\mathbb R ^n$. There is something I don't get right in the OP?

Answer (score 1):

The first answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4279194/existence-of-isometry-into-mathbbrn?rq=1) shows that there is no such isometry for any choice of $n\in \mathbb{N}$. However, there exists an isometry between $(\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{Z}),d)$ and $(c_{00}(\mathbb{Z}), \rho)$ where $c_{00}(\mathbb{Z})$ is the space of finitely supported sequences indexed on $\mathbb{Z}$
and $\rho$ is the metric induced by the $\ell^1$ norm. This is easily seen by defining $f: \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{Z}) \to c_{00}(\mathbb{Z})$ for each finite subset $A$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ according to the following rule:
$$f(A)_k=\mathbb{1}_A(k) \; \text{for all } k\in \mathbb{Z}$$
and noting that it is an isometry.

Answer (score 1):

There is an isometry between $(\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{Z}), d)$ and $\mathbb R ^ \mathbb N$ using the $L1$ distance. A subset $A$ of $\mathbb Z$ is represented by a vector $V = \sum_{i \in A} e_i$ where $(e_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ is $\mathbb R ^ \mathbb N$ base. The summation is finite.

This is similar to what @GiorgosGiapitzakis answered, except the set tries to come closer to $\mathbb R ^ n$. But anyway it is strange such a problem with a false conclusion is posed. Where does it come from?